# Jquery ajax loaded content refuses jquery to work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am keen on mastering Codeigniter and jQuery for web app dev.

I have links where I click and they fill up a div with content and this works but I use the $.ajax({}); not get or post or load. now the thing I noticed and I know it's not new is anything I try to do with jquery on the fetched content does not work.

So even if I do a console.log() to try and catch a click event on a submit button nothing happens. The form just moves away from the page currently being worked on. So my question is what are noobs to do in this instance? is it a setting or an option?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) to bind functions to events for elements that get added after page load. Basically, live() will bind code to events firing on all existing and future elements that match a certain selector.

Comment: dude,

your answer was spot on. I suspected the answer was close. Thanks a million.

God bless.